# Magento 2 access Rest API interface from root file

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I have created a script file in root and I want to create a new customer from that file below is my code for that.

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
//use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
 
require __DIR__ . '/../../app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State')->setAreaCode('frontend');

$customerData = [
        'customer' => [
            'email' => 'demo@user.com',
            'firstname' => 'John',
            'lastname' => 'Wick',
           ],
        'password' => 'John123'
    ];

$customer=$obj->get('\Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface');
$customer->createAccount($customerData);
```

but when i run this code it gives me below error.

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement\Interceptor::createAccount() must be an instance of Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface, array given, called in C:\wamp64\www\mg\m2\rest\v3\Customer.php on line 82 and defined in C:\wamp64\www\mg\m2\generated\code\Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement\Interceptor.php:124
Stack trace:

## 0 C:\wamp64\www\mg\m2\rest\v3\Customer.php(82): Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement\Interceptor->createAccount(Array)

## 1 C:\wamp64\www\mg\m2\rest\v3\api.php(7): require_once('C:\wamp64\www\m...')

## 2 {main}

thrown in
**C:\wamp64\www\mg\m2\generated\code\Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement\Interceptor.php** on line
**124**

Please help. actually i want to access web api method directly from code and get response so that i can modify that response accordingly. because we already have app running in magento 1.9. so we don't want to change response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just like the error message says. You have to pass an implementation of `Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface` to the `createAccount` method.

So instead of passing a simple array like `$customerData`, you should create a new instance of a CustomerInterface implementation instead ... and fill it with the required data.

Searching through their github repo I found this:
`Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer`
https://github.com/magento/magento2/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22implements+Magento%5CCustomer%5CApi%5CData%5CCustomerInterface%22&type=

So unless you want to create your own implementation, this is what you should pass to `createAccount`

You should be able to create one via the factory like so:

```
try {
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

    $objectManager->get(Magento\Framework\App\State::class)
        ->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND);

    /** @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerFactory */
    $customerFactory = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory::class);
    $customer = $customerFactory->create();
    $customer
        ->setEmail('justincase@test123.xyz')
        ->setFirstname('Justin')
        ->setLastname('Case');

    /** @var \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface $accountManager */
    $accountManager = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface::class);
    $accountManager->createAccount($customer);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Ok, since I was curious, I quickly (lol) installed magento2 myself. With the above example I was able to create a customer on a fresh magento2 install.

Comment: Unless the CustomerInterfaceFactory does actually return something other than an instance of a CustomerInterface implementation, that should be impossible. If all else fails, you may want to debug the actual signup/account creation in PhpStorm/Eclipse/VSCode etc.